# Tree to grid node dragging working in Ext4.0 but 4.1

Tags: extjs, drag, extjs4.1, gridpanel, treepanel

I've a tree-panel as

```
var t = new Ext.TreePanel({
    .
    .
    store: <loaded dynamically>
    viewConfig: {
        allowCopy: true,
        copy: true,
        plugins:{
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'dragGroup',
            dragText: 'Place the node to grid'
        }
    }
});
```

And a grid-panel as

```
var bpMappingGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    columns:[
    {
        header:'Application Name',
        dataIndex:'applicationName', //The same name should be there in treenode too
        align:'center',
        width:150
    },{
        header:'Tagged BusinessProcess',
        dataIndex:'businessProcessName', //The same name should be there in treenode too
        align:'center',
        width:180
    }
    ],
    store: <loaded dynamically>,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins:{
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dropGroup: 'dragGroup'
        }
    }
});
```

Every node has an associated `businessProcessName` and `applicationName`. So when we drag a node, it assigns the corresponding values of these data indices to the grid.

**This code works fine in ExtJS 4.0 but its inserting an empty row in the grid in ExtJS 4.1.
Please tell me how to make it working for ExtJS 4.1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both the tree grid and regular grid have models defined that contain the fields: businessProcessName and applicationName.